# How to get back to previous view when select one row of current table view

Tags: swift, uitableview

My class is extend from UIViewController, and there is one tableView and one button in it, which is displayed or hidden according to conditions.

I use extension: UITableViewDataSource to provide the data for tableView. And I want app to get back to previous view when user select any row of tableView. But I found that I cannot use `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` inside extension {}, it is reasonable UITableViewDataSource doesn't include this method.

But I want to know how could I implement this method in my case. Below is the code, any hint or help is appreciated!

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddSongToPlaylistFromCell: UIViewController {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    var pplist = [Playlist]()
    var playlistObjects = [Playlist]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var addPlaylistButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")

        do {
            pplist = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        // if no playlist created yet
        if pplist.count == 0 {
            tableView.isHidden = true
        } else {
            // get playlist info from Playlist entity
            // self.getPlaylistProperties()
            addPlaylistButton.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Playlist>(entityName: "Playlist")

        do {
            playlistObjects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        // refresh table data.
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


    @IBAction func addPlaylist(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Name", message: "Please enter new playlist name", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) {
            [unowned self] action in

            guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first, let nameToSave = textField.text else {
                return
            }

            self.save(name: nameToSave)
            self.tableView.reloadData()


            self.tableView.isHidden = false
            self.addPlaylistButton.isHidden = true

        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)

        // add textField to alert
        alert.addTextField()
        alert.addAction(saveAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        present(alert, animated: true)
    }

    func save(name: String) {
        // save playlist name to Entity Playlist
        let playlist = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Playlist", into: self.context) as! Playlist

        playlist.name = name

        do {
            try self.context.save()
            playlistObjects.append(playlist)
            print("Save OK!")
        } catch {
            fatalError("Can not save: \(error)")
        }
    }


    @IBAction func NaviBack(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        // self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension AddSongToPlaylistFromCell: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // print("count", playlistObjects.count)
        return playlistObjects.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let playlist = playlistObjects[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = playlist.value(forKeyPath: "name") as? String
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Album-50")

        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate), maybe make another extension (similar to the one you've used for UITableViewDataSource:

```
// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate
extension AddSongToPlaylistFromCell: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I add this ```extension AddSongToPlaylistFromCell: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("another extension")
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}``` in my code, but when selecting the row, nothing happen, no print() no navi back...

Comment: @ChuckZHB Add `tableView.delegate = self` in your viewDidLoad.

Comment: yes! just find that too when go through other similar questions. After adding ```tableView.delegate = self```, then tableView(... didSelectRowAt) func is connected and could be called. Thanks, that fix my issue:)

Comment: @ChuckZHB Glad it's sorted, feel free to mark my post as the solution :)